# Is there an easy way to have a non-IDENTITY, auto incrementing column based on another column?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, schema

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| ID | ProductName | ProductCategory | ProductCode |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Item 1      |               1 |           1 |
|  2 | Item 2      |               1 |           2 |
|  3 | Item 3      |               2 |           1 |
|  4 | Item 4      |               3 |           1 |
|  5 | Item 5      |               1 |           3 |
|  6 | Item 6      |               2 |           2 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is have a column autoincrement but based on the last row in the same ProductCategory.

Currently I have a stored procedure that does the following

```
SELECT TOP 1 @NextProductCode = ProductCode + 1 
  FROM Products 
 WHERE ProductCategory = @ProductCategory
```

This works, but despite the fact that this is a pretty low traffic database there's an obvious concurrency issue here. I could throw a `TABLOCKX` in the stored procedure I guess but I'm curious if there's a more simple way to accomplish this.

I'm also trying to avoid dynamic SQL otherwise I could create a sequence for each new ProductCategory.

Comment: Yes, `ProductCategory` is a foreign key to the `Category` table

Comment: Add a counter in your Category table and an SP that SELECT WITH (UPDLOCK), increment, and UPDATE this counter or an UPDATE with OUTPUT that increments this counter.

Comment: @McNets - That looks more like an answer than a comment, you know....

Comment: @McNets so something like this?

`SELECT @NextProdCode = Category.NextCode FROM Category WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE Category.ID = @ProductCategory`

Followed by an update, all wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: Use the MAX() function instead of Top. It is optimized for this purpose and also makes reading your code clearer as top may or may not return the latest value available.

Answer (score 1):

If I am Understanding you correctly, you are looking to select a group of product that's already in a DB, and assign a new Product ID to each Product that is Unique to each Product Category, if this is correct then you can add this to your SELECT statement,

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCategory ORDER BY ID) AS ProductCode`

it should do what you are looking for.

Comment: If a row is deleted, row_number() may return a number that is already in use.

Comment: Deleting rows would be considered very poor inventory management for a company.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of search in Products table for last product_id, I'd suggest to add a counter to the `Category` table.

Now, you can use `SELECT ... WITH (UPDLOCK)`

- Have a look at [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114575/110455) of Paul White or at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017) about table HINTS.

```
DECLARE @ProductCode int = 0;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT
    @ProductCode = ProductCode + 1
FROM
    Category WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE
    ID = 1;

UPDATE
    Category
SET
    ProductCode = @ProductCode
WHERE
    ID = 1;

-- Insert new products using @ProductCode

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

or you can take advantage of [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @ProductCode int = 0;
DECLARE @t TABLE (PCode int);

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE
    Category
SET
    ProductCode = ProductCode + 1
OUTPUT 
    inserted.ProductCode INTO @t
WHERE
    ID = 1;

SELECT 
    @ProductCode = PCode 
FROM 
    @t;

-- Insert new products using @ProductCode

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ec7582fd4a4ba05d0f9d8b791a83bf7)*</kbd>